# Node lambda funtion obtener la response

Tags: nodejs, aws, https, lambda

soy nuevo con Node js y Lambda y me esta costando resolver esto.
Lo que quiero crear es una función en Lambda que hace una GET request a la API de Google Page Speed y que me devuelva en la respuesta la informacion de Google page speed. (y que luego me imprima en una API Gateaway el JSON de la consulta a la API de Google)
Alguna idea que estoy haciendo mal?

```
 
 var https = require('https');
    exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var API_KEY= "MY_API_KEY";
    let rawData;
    var params = {
                host: "pagespeedonline.googleapis.com",
                path: `/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.unapaginacualquiera.com%2F&key=${API_KEY}`
                };
    var req = https.request(params, function(res) {
    console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        // body.push(chunk);
        rawData += chunk;
    });
    res.on('end', function() {
        
        console.log("DONE");
        console.log(rawData);
        try {
            callback(null, `Data coming: ${rawData}`);
            } catch (e) {
      console.error(e.message);
    }
    });
  });
  req.end();
 };
```

Comment: ¿Qué respuesta obtienes del servidor? Tu API key no es realmente `"MY_API_KEY"`, ¿Estás usando otro valor verdad?

Comment: Hola, si claro. Obviamente. Y esa pagina tampoco existe, puse una de ejemplo. Ahora modifique el codigo y tengo como respuesta la informacion, pero no la tengo en formato JSON como me gustaria que se despliegue. Ahi actualizo el codigo

Comment: ¿Ya intentaste paresarlo con `JSON.parse(rawData )`? ¿O del todo la respuesta no tiene formato JSON?

Comment: Por alguna extraña razón si hago el JSON.parse(rawData) la respuesta me da null

Comment: ¿Has probado usar una herramienta como `postman` para comprobar la integridad de los datos o el request en sí, antes de realizar la implementación? Esto podría ayudarte a ver qué está pasando.

Comment: Si, en postman me llega la información correctamente. Y en la función de Lambda tambien me llega la información. Solo que no logro que se me imprima en formato JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas inicializar `rawData` como una string, así:

```
let rawData="";
```